# C++/QT- Simulate press key after received data

Tags: c++, qt

I want to simulate press F5 key in other application for example Firefox. I have program which minimalize to tray system and recaived data but I have problem with this part of code. I can't found solutuion for my problem.
Anyone can help me ?
Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: You can't do that in Qt, you will have to use your platform specific libraries.

Comment: But you can create a browser window inside your Qt app quite easily and then you can do whatever you want with that

Comment: Thanks for answers. But I resolved my problem with windows.h library and keybd_event function.

Comment: Poory defined question. If you are trying to catch `F5` inside Qt app, use event handler.

Comment: @KernelPanic I am not going to catch F5 event, but i want to simulate this event in other window.

Comment: If you resolved your problem, please post your solution as an answer to help others

Answer (score 0):

This part of code resolved my problem in 100%. When I received data from serial port I call this keyboard event and in Firefox I see refreshing of page.
`#include <windows.h>
keybd_event(VK_F5, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_F5, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);`